# Running a simple Parse cloud function manually?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

So I have downloaded the Parse command line tool and deployed the following simple main.js file:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("initialFunction", function(request, response){
    var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("TestClass");
    var testObject = new TestObject();
    testObject.save({Celebrity: name}).then(function(object) {
        console.log("yay! it worked");
    });
}
```

Then in the index.html file I try to run this by including the parse cdn, initializing parse and running the following script:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('initialFunction', {}, {
    success: function(ratings) {
        // ratings should be 4.5
    },
    error: function(error) {
    }
});
```

However, my database remains unchanged when I run this.. 
I check the logs on Parse.com and they don't seem to output any valuable information...

So does anyone know how I should be calling this cloud function correctly?